# Family of projective curve is proper?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\rightarrow S$ be flat morphism such that for each fiber $X_s$ is a projective curve. Is that also true that $X\rightarrow S$ is also projective or at least proper?

Comment: Not without further assumptions - consider $S=\Bbb A^1$, $X=\Bbb A^1\times\Bbb P^1$, and let the morphism be the natural projection.

Comment: Thank you very much. I make a wrong question. I want to ask the properties of the morphism $X\rightarrow S$.